# Comparing two string variables in puppet template

Tags: puppet, erb

I'm trying to write an if statement that compares two variables in a puppet erb template:

```
<% @array_of_ip_addresses.each_with_index do |ip, idx| -%>
  <% if @ip == @ipaddress_eth0 -%>
    <%= "doing something with #{idx}" -%>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

I cannot figure out why, but the condition on my if statement keeps returning false (needless to say I confirmed there should be a match).

What dumb thing am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ip` is a block scope variable and not a variable instantiated from the invoking code (in this case, Puppet's `template` function), so you should not specify it as a class instance variable with `@`. When you remove that and specify it as a block scope variable `ip`, the template will look like:

```
<% @array_of_ip_addresses.each_with_index do |ip, idx| -%>
  <% if ip == @ipaddress_eth0 -%>
    <%= "doing something with #{idx}" -%>
  <% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Using the class instance variable `@ip` would likely result in a resolution of `nil`, which would definitely almost always be false as `nil != @ipaddress_eth0` unless Facter failed to resolve a value for your eth0 ipaddress, which would be quite uncommon (but still possible).

Comment: Dude, you rock!